# Why is the root diameter of hair not changing?

Tags: particles

I opened a new project with a simple cube, added a particle, changed the particle setting to hair, went down to hair shapes and adjusted the root diameter. I cranked the value up as high as it would go, to 10m and it does nothing to the hair.  What am I missing? It's 3:30am here and I've searched everywhere. everything I watch seems to show me that what I'm doing should work but it doesn't.[image]

Answer (score 2):

You need to be in *Rendered* viewport shading mode to see the thickness:

[image]

Also, if you are in Eevee, until Blender 3.1 you need to go into the *Render* panel > *Hair* and press on *Strip*:

[image]

From 3.2.1 it's under *Render > Curves*:

[image]

Comment: In 3.2.1 it's under _Curves_ in the _Render Properties_.

Comment: @Gordon Brinkmann oh great thank you

Comment: Ok, Sorry I still can't figure it out. I just updated to the latest version and I'm still having the same problem.  Can someone please send a screen shot of were this is located? Thank you. Just pretend you are talking to a dumb a$$.

Comment: @Ryan Kenneth Jones, I've edited, I hope it helps

Comment: Perfect!  Holy crap, I can't believe that worked.  You are so awesome.... thank you so much for your time!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: This is the video I was watching trying to learn how to make curly hair. 
 The setting you showed me allowed me to do what this girl was showing in her video. so thank you very much and maybe this video will help someone else who is wanting to make curly hair. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZOkGwcObYBA&t=129s